Mouse acceleration change after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04
Did the default profile for mouse acceleration change in ubuntu 22.04?
I just upgraded 20.04 to 22.04 on one machine and the cursor behaves differently. Especially when the mouse moves slowly - it moves the cursor much further and with less precision than in 20.04' default profile.
Is there a way to manually adjust the acceleration other than switching between 3 profiles in gnome tweaks?
Thanks

Ubuntu 20 and 22 are versions of Ubuntu Core. If this is not what you are using please edit the question and use the actual version info.

Even if you are using both versions on a single machine or different machines, you can set different cursor speeds by heading to Settings->Mouse & Touchpad->Pointer Speed

Yes thanks i know. The issue is not the mouse speed itself, but the acceleration when the mouse moves slowly. If i would put it on the scale, from slowest to fastest, this is what it looks like: 1. flat profile (no acceleration) -> 2. default acceleration profile on 20.04 -> 3. default acceleration profile on 22.04. Where the difference between each is significant.
Other thing, may it be related to the mouse iself? I don't see such a huge difference when i use a touchpad.
